# FB.AppRequest not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to invite my friends to a unity game using FB.Apprequest()
Friends' selection window is appearing but when I select friends and press send button, no request/notifications are sent to my friends. My logs say :

```
07-07 16:02:39.685: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(26877): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success?request=834779373275750&to%5B0%5D=10153376852521772
07-07 16:02:39.686: V/FBUnitySDK(26877): sending to Unity OnAppRequestsComplete({"to[0]":"10153376852521772","request":"834779373275750","callback_id":"2"})
```

Comment: are you doing this from the editor. The facebook SKD supports less and less stuff from the editor which each new version.

Comment: no I am doing it on mobile

Comment: Where do you collect the logs?

Comment: Also good to know, notifications are only surfaced on platforms your app is set up to support. So if you're Android only for example, notifications would only show in the Android app. Also (as far as I know), users can turn off such notifications.

Comment: You may want to see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263438/fb-apprequest-does-not-work/