# FB.AppRequest does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am trying to send App Requests with Facebook SDK on Unity. Everything is alright until I press 'send'. It also returns a success but nothing happens in my friends' facebook :S

```
    FB.AppRequest(message, null, null, null, null, null, title,
        (result) => {
            Debug.Log(result.RawResult);
        }
    );
```

As you can see, I am able to show the friends list and select the ones who will receive the request. After pressing send, it returns a success(I have put the Xs intentionally). However, nothing happens on my friend's facebook.

```
{"to":"10XXXXXXXXXXXXXX33","request":"161XXXXXXXXXXXXXX89","callback_id":"4"}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the request show up under More > App > App Invites in the native app? If yes, then it is working as expected. Also, the notifications will only show up in the platforms you have added in the App Settings. For example, if you have only added iOS as a supported platform, you wont see the invites in www or Android.

Comment: I am testing on Android devices which is added on the supported devices. However, I cannot see it on App Invites. My app is in development mode. That might be the problem? In development mode, I am able to post things but invite?

Comment: Development mode might be an issue..try and send the request to a user who has a role in the app such as an admin or a developer and see if they are able to see it.

Comment: Sending someone with the role solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Bangdel saved the day! Was trying to see the app requests in the desktop/web and my game is only for android. Checked within the Facebook Android App and both App Requests and App Invites were there! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assigned my friend receiving the request as administrator so that he was able to get the notification. Otherwise, he does not get anything because the facebook app is currently in development mode.

Comment: I tried this - adding a friend as a developer - and they didn't get the notification, however it works when sending the request between test users (properly created test users in the developer console) - the test user receives the notification. Could development mode still be causing the issue?

Comment: My friend and I were both admins in that case. I am not sure about your case because I cannot reproduce it currently.

Comment: no problem, thanks for trying - just curious, when your friend click the request notification where does it take them? For me it just shows a 'content not found' page, like the link is wrong, but I don't know where to set it - my app is in dev mode, and alpha test mode on the play store